# ¿Por que no funciona mi .foreach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Segun mi visual code esto funciona, pero segun el corrector del examen de ingreso de Henry no. Si alguien encuentra el motivo por el cual se supone que no anda o si sabe como hacerlo con un forin, estaría muy agradecido.

```
function cuantosOnline(usuarios) {
  // La funcion llamada "cuantosOnline" recibe como argumento un objeto 'usuarios', cada property de ese objeto es un objeto
  // cada usuario tiene una property 'online' que es un booleano.
  // deberia devolver la cantidad de usuarios con la property online igual a true.
  // Por ej:
  // let usuarios = {
  //     toni: {
  //         edad: 33,
  //         online: true
  //     },
  //     emi: {
  //         edad: 25,
  //         online: true
  //     },
  //     fran: {
  //         edad: 25,
  //         online: false
  //     },
  //     agus: {
  //         edad: 24,
  //         online: false
  //     }
  // }; 
  // cuantosOnline(usuarios) devuelve 2
  // Tip: Podes usar el metodo for...in

  // Tu código aca:

  
    var verdaderos =0, falsos = 0;
  
    for (let user in usuarios){
      console.log("hola")
      user.online === true ? verdaderos++ : falsos++;
    }
    return verdaderos, falsos;
    
}
```

//estoy intentando pero la verdad es que no entiendo como lograr de que tome //a los online como true

Comment: Toma en cuenta que `forEach` es un método de los Array, y usuarios es un Objeto, por lo tanto seguramente recibes un error: `TypeError: usuarios.forEach is not a function`. Antes de intentar resolver un ejercicio es muy conveniente que leas toda la documentación referente a las variables implicadas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias mauricio pero la verdad me serviria mucho que me des un pequeño ejemplo si no es mucha molestia, estuve toda la mañana tratando de lograr que esta funcion funcione con for In pero siempre que le preguntaba si online es == true directamente no me respondia.

Comment: En JS no necesitas comparar una variable booleana con su valor, sin embargo, dado que estás empezando es buena práctica hacerlo. La comparación que deberías implementar es la comparación estricta (===). Puedes recorrer los objetos anidados usando un bucle [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), por ejemplo: `for (let user in usuarios) { ... }`

Comment: Luego, podrías hacer esto dentro del bucle: `user.online === true ? verdaderos++ : falsos++;`. Puedes leer sobre el [operador condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) y sobre la [igualdad estricta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). Recuerda que debes implementar una función llamada `"cuantosOnline"` que implemente toda esta lógica y devuelva la cantidad de verdaderos. Saludos

Comment: Perdon otra vez por las molestias pero intento usar el formato que usted explica y no logro hacerlo funcionar, edite el codigo para mostrarle lo que puse

Comment: @JuanLópez La razón por la que tu código no funciona es la siguiente: cuando declaras un `for (let user in usuarios)` en cada iteración de tu ciclo la variable `user` no es como tal un usuario con propiedades como tu esperas, lo que guarda `user` es solo el nombre de ese usuario. Por tanto para acceder a sus propiedades debes utilizar esa llave en el objeto original `usuarios[user].online === true ? verdaderos++ : falsos++;`. Cambiando solo esta última línea tu código funcionará.

Comment: Por otro lado, no entiendo que relación tiene el método `.foreach` con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que tu código no funciona es la siguiente:

1. Cuando declaras un `for (let user in usuarios)` siendo `usuarios` un objeto, en cada iteración de tu ciclo la variable `user` no es como tal un usuario con propiedades como tu esperas, lo que guarda `user` es solo el nombre de ese usuario, es decir, `user` es solo un `string` que representa la clave en el objeto. Recuerda siempre lo siguiente y es super importante:

> Cuando iteras en un objeto con `for(..in..)` la variable del `for` tomará en cada iteración las **claves del objeto**.

Es decir, que en el primer ciclo user valdrá `toni`, en el segundo valdrá `emi` y así. Como ves, son puros `strings`, no tienen como tal ninguna propiedad. Para acceder a la propiedad `online` que buscas debes hacerlo con `usuarios[user].online`. Y ese es justo el único arreglo que necesita tu código. Quise respetarlo lo más posible para que tu esfuerzo valiera la pena. Acá te dejo un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar.

```js
let usuarios = {
    toni: {
        edad: 33,
        online: true
    },
    emi: {
        edad: 25,
        online: true
    },
    fran: {
        edad: 25,
        online: false
    },
    agus: {
        edad: 24,
        online: false
    }
}; 



function cuantosOnline(usuarios) {
  // La funcion llamada "cuantosOnline" recibe como argumento un objeto 'usuarios', cada property de ese objeto es un objeto
  // cada usuario tiene una property 'online' que es un booleano.
  // deberia devolver la cantidad de usuarios con la property online igual a true.
  // Por ej:
  // cuantosOnline(usuarios) devuelve 2
  // Tip: Podes usar el metodo for...in

  // Tu código aca:  
    var verdaderos =0, falsos = 0;
  
    for (let user in usuarios){
      console.log(user)
      usuarios[user].online === true ? verdaderos++ : falsos++;
    }
    return verdaderos;
}

console.log(` Hay ${cuantosOnline(usuarios)} usuarios online`)
```

Comment: Agregué respuesta ya que en las variantes que te daban solo optan por convertir de manera innecesaria el objeto a un array, lo cual es totalmente válido pero no es para nada requerido. Además quería respetar tu código que realmente necesitaba solo una mínima correción.

Answer (score 0):

Probe tu codigo en el navegador y pude hacer que funcione.

```
function cuantosOnline(param_usuarios) {

/*
    Primer error: 
    Esta funcion tiene un parametro llamado usuarios
    y estas redeclarando esta variable; esto te dara un error:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'usuarios' has already been declared
    lo que podrias hacer es nombrar el objeto usuarios o el parametro con otro nombre
    En este caso renombre el parametro param_usuarios para que
    no de ningun error
*/
let usuarios = {
    toni: {
        edad: 33,
        online: true
    },
    emi: {
        edad: 25,
        online: true
    },
    fran: {
        edad: 25,
        online: false
    },
    agus: {
        edad: 24,
        online: false
    }
};

var falsos = 0, verdaderos = 0;

/*
  Segundo error:
  Aqui, como te dijo @Mauricio, el metodo forEach() no 
  va a funcionar porque usuarios es un objeto, no un arreglo
  (array) por lo que te dara el este error:
  Uncaught TypeError: usuarios.forEach is not a function

  para convertir un objeto a un arreglo puedes usar 
  la funcion Object.values
*/
// usuarios.forEach(el=> el.online ? verdaderos ++ : falsos ++);



//convertir usuarios a un array y asignandolo a la misma variable usuarios
usuarios = Object.values(usuarios);

//ahora si puedes usar un forEach 
 usuarios.forEach(el => el.online ? verdaderos++ : falsos++);


// for(let user in usuarios){
//     usuarios[user].online === true ? verdaderos++ : falsos++;
// }

    return verdaderos;
}
```

Funciona en mi navegador, la funcion retorna 2.Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta al comentario de @AryRodny:

> Anora, tambien podrias implementar el loop "for of".
> Ojo, no "for in". for in te dara un error porque el objeto
> usuarios (ahora un array) tiene otros objetos adentro.
> no datos simples.

Aquí se ve una implementación usando el bucle `for in`, sin errores y con el resultado esperado.

```js
let usuarios = {
    toni: {
        edad: 33,
        online: true
    },
    emi: {
        edad: 25,
        online: true
    },
    fran: {
        edad: 25,
        online: false
    },
    agus: {
        edad: 24,
        online: false
    }
};

var falsos = 0, verdaderos = 0;


//convertir usuarios a un array y asignandolo a la misma variable usuarios
usuarios = Object.values(usuarios);

for(const index in usuarios){
/* 
 * Es perfectamente viable usar un bucle for in,
 * aunque tal vez no sea lo más "normal" en estos casos. 
 * Simplemente debemos tener en cuenta que lo que tenemos en el 
 * bucle son los índices, pero como se ve, se pueden usar 
 * perfectamente para recorrer el array!
 */
  if (usuarios[index].online) {
    verdaderos++;
  }
}

console.log(`Hay ${verdaderos} usuarios online`);
```

Comment: quise decir que no funciona. No es que da un error, es que la variable verdaderos devolvia 0. Ahora me doy cuenta que es porque estaba llamando la propiedad online en el indice user. asi, user.online en vez de usuarios[user].online. Gracias por la correcion.

Answer (score 0):

Con filter()

```js
let usuarios = {
    toni: {
        edad: 33,
        online: true
    },
    emi: {
        edad: 25,
        online: true
    },
    fran: {
        edad: 25,
        online: false
    },
    agus: {
        edad: 24,
        online: false
    }
};
usuarios = Object.values(usuarios);
let filtro=usuarios.filter(usu=>usu.online==true);
let online=filtro.length
console.log(`Hay ${online} usuarios online`)
```